# Is it possible to "invert" function masking by different packages?

Tags: r, package, r-package

I maintain a package for use in the company where I work. Not all the programmers are as diligent as they arguably should be, and they often spam `library()` calls for every package they'll ever need. This often leads to functions from one package being masked by another which is loaded later, which then leads to complications and weird bugs elsewhere in the code. These bugs are then solved by using the `package::function` syntax, which just looks weird when it's used for one package function but nothing else around it, even from other functions from the same package (which weren't masked).

Obviously, the proper thing to do in such cases would be to not load every single package with `library()`, saving that for the most commonly used packages in the code and then using the `package::function` syntax for the ones used less frequently.

However, that's beyond my control. So I'm trying to help the programmers by adding a function to our internal package which handles package "priority", letting them define which package should take precedence when a given function name is called.

The following code works:

```r
setDefaultPackage <- function(pkg, functions = NULL) {
    pkg = paste0("package:", pkg)
    
    if (is.null(functions)) functions <- utils::lsf.str(pkg)
    
    for(f in functions) {
        # only reassign if name doesn't yet exist or if associated environment is
        # NOT the global environment.
        
        if (exists(f)) {
            canUnmask <- tryCatch({
                getNamespaceName(environment(get(f, pos = parent.frame())))
                TRUE
            }, error = function (e) {
                FALSE
            })
        } else {
            canUnmask <- TRUE
        }
        
        if (canUnmask) {
            x <- tryCatch({
                get(pos = pkg, f)
            }, error = function(e) {
                stop("Package ", pkg, "does not have a function called ", f)
            })
            
            assign(f, x, pos = parent.frame())
        }
    }
}

library(stats)
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "stats"

# now mask stats::filter with dplyr::filter
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "dplyr"

# restore stats::filter to the top
setDefaultPackage("stats")
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "stats"

# restore dplyr::filter to the top
setDefaultPackage("dplyr")
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "dplyr"

# Fails to unmask packaged names masked by local names
filter <- function() {print(1)}
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "R_GlobalEnv"

setDefaultPackage("stats")
environmentName(environment(filter))
#> [1] "R_GlobalEnv" -- (unchanged!) --
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The user can define whether they want `filter` to call `stats::filter` or `dplyr::filter`.

However, this function is very inelegant: it works by defining function names in the local frame (in the examples above, the global frame; if called within another function, the calling function's frame), flooding that frame's namespace.

[image]

In this case, the namespace is flooded with object names from both `stats` and `dplyr`, since I've called `setDefaultPackage` for both (the conflicting names currently point to `stats` since that was my last call).

A much cleaner way of doing this would be to simply modify the search path:

```r
search()
#> [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
#> [9] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Since I loaded `dplyr` after `stats`, it comes first in the search list.

If I could simply modify that list, shuffling `package:dplyr` and `package:stats` around, that'd be fantastic. Is that possible?

That is, is there a way to put a specific package at the top of the search list?

```r
someMagicalFunction("stats")
search()
#> [1] ".GlobalEnv"      "package:stats"     "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
#> [9] "package:methods" "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Comment: Maybe check out the [conflicted](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/06/conflicted/) package (specifically `conflicted::conflict_prefer`). Values are added to the search path in the same order that `library()` calls are made. Unfortunately `stats` is auto loaded for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following customized function:

```
setDefaultPackage <- function(pkg, functions = NULL){
  pkg1 <- paste0("package:", pkg)
  nms <- paste(pkg, 'functions', sep = '_')
  if (is.null(functions))  {
    if (any(search() == pkg1)) 
      detach(pkg1, character.only = TRUE)
    library(pkg, character.only = TRUE)
  }
  else {
    if (any(search() == nms)) 
      detach(nms, character.only = TRUE)
    env <- list2env(mget(functions, as.environment(pkg1)))
    attach(env, name = nms)
  }
}
```

example:

```
> library(dplyr)
> search()
 #> [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
 #> [5] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 #> [9] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Now if you want to prioritize all the functions in `stats` package:

```
> setDefaultPackage('stats')

#> Attaching package: ‘stats’

#> The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

#>    filter, lag

> search()
#> [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"    
#> [5] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
#> [9] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

We see that `stats` package comes before the `dplyr` package meaning we could use `lag` and `filter` from `stats` package.

Lets revert it back so that `dplry` comes before `stats`:

```
> setDefaultPackage('dplyr')
> search()
 #> [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
 #> [5] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 #> [9] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

What if from the beginning, we want to use the `lag` from `dplyr` but `filter` from `stats`??
ie in the search path, dplyr comes before stats, just like before. Then you could run

> setDefaultPackage('stats', 'filter')

Now the `filter` to be used is from `stats`, while `lag` is from `dplyr`.